# Does OpenCV for Mac use the Accelerate framework?

Tags: opencv, accelerate-framework

The Accelerate framework is a Mac-specific framework that provides things like image convolutions and LAPACK, supposedly optimized to be as fast as possible on Macs. My question: Does OpenCV take advantage of this? Specifically, does the function "filter2D" use Accelerate?

Answer (score 2):

It does not use the Accelerate framework, but it looks like it has been speeded up using the CUDA stuff in 2.2

The relevant files in OpenCV2.2 ...

/modules/gpu/include/opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp
/modules/gpu/src/filtering.cpp

and

modules/imgproc/src/filter.cpp

for the non-gpu stuff

Answer (score 1):

Not a mac expert but AFAIK openCV uses [IPP](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-ipp/) (if installed) [TBB](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/) (build option) and [NVidia-CUDA](http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda_home.html) (build option)

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org) version, you can specify the options

```
$ port variants opencv
opencv has the variants:
   debug: Enable debug binaries
   python26: Add Python 2.6 bindings
     * conflicts with python27
   python27: Add Python 2.7 bindings
     * conflicts with python26
   tbb: Use Intel TBB
   universal: Build for multiple architectures
```

I have used

```
sudo port install py26-numpy
sudo port install opencv +python26 +tbb
```

with success. Concerning the Accelerate.framework specifically, this [blog entry](http://niw.at/articles/2009/03/14/using-opencv-on-iphone/en) says "# Add Accelerate.framework which is used internally from OpenCV library.", but I have no clue as to know if it is the case here.